# Grammar not recognizing || (OR) operator

Tags: java, antlr, grammar

I have the following grammar:

```
 cond_stmt: ('('cond_stmt')'|('!' cond_stmt)| cond_expr|cond_or|cond_and) ;
 cond_or: cond_expr(OR cond_stmt)+;
 cond_and: cond_expr(AND cond_stmt)+;
 OR:'||';
 AND: '&&';
 BLANK: ['\b'|'\t'|' ']+ -> skip;
```

ANTLR can recognize conditional statement with `&&` operator like `a>5 && b<6`
but it is not able to recognize `a>5 || b<6`
It ignores the `||` operator and says not viable input `a>5b`
If there are no spaces in between the conditional statements then it can recognize it.
e.g `a>5||b<6` is recognized.

Does anyone know why this is the case? I'm new to the antlr if you find some issues or improvements with the grammar please tell them.

Comment: What's the ***question***?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: I'm guessing "why doesn't it work and how do I fix it?" is the missing piece of the puzzle :)

Comment: It doesn't say 'not viable input', surely. Tell us what it *really* says, all of it. Don't paraphrase error messages.

Comment: you guys have downvoted my question now i coudn't upload the image for the question start: OR;
     OR:'||';
doesn't recognize || http://i.stack.imgur.com/gpqJi.png

Comment: Your example is far from complete, but I think you have the full grammar with you. The answer is on the last line:

    `BLANK: ['\b'|'\t'|' ']+ -> skip ;`

In a regex, something in square brackets means: *one of the following characters*, here `|` is just a character. The way to specify *one of the following groups* is with the parentheses. So you want to use:

    `BLANK: ('\b'|'\t'|' ')+ -> skip ;`. Without the spaces was passing because you probably had a greedy match somewhere else in the grammar, but surely not constructing the correct tree.

Comment: Thanks @enrico.bacis you are right it is fixed now .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @enrico.bacis you are right it is fixed now .

```
     **incorrect**
    BLANK: ['\b'|'\t'|' ']+ -> skip;
   **CORRECT**
    BLANK: ('\b'|'\t'|' ')+ -> skip ;
```